# Images with absolute positioned texts

Tags: html, css

I want to reproduce the 4 square images on this page:https://pura-moringa.de/ -> scroll down 1 time

[image]

But I just can't figure out how to do this.. How do I get the text over the image in all 4 squares?

This is my code (tried to copy it from the page to understand it, but does not work)

This is one square:

```
   <div class="col-xs-6">
<div class="minibanner is-square">
<img class="minibanner-image" src="https://pura-moringa.de/skin/frontend/copimaj/default/images/minibanners/moringa-feel-good.jpg" alt="7 Gründe, warum du dich mit Moringa besser fühlst"/>
<div class="minibanner-content">
<h3>10 Gründe, warum du dich mit Moringa besser fühlst</h3>
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="https://pura-moringa.de/moringa-wirkung" title="10 Gründe, warum du dich mit Moringa besser fühlst">Mehr erfahren</a>
</div>
<a class="overlay" href="https://pura-moringa.de/moringa-wirkung" title="10 Gründe, warum du dich mit Moringa besser fühlst"/>
</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rrbb2L5j/#&togetherjs=CtR9J6JfnD

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using absolute position

```
.minibanner-content{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
.minibanner.is-square{
  position:relative;
}
```